# Adding WP Custom Logo as Webp image in Timber

Tags: wordpress, twig, wordpress-theming, webp, timber

I'm using the [Timber starter theme](https://github.com/timber/starter-theme) and I'm getting hung up on adding the logo from the WP dashboard. First thing I did is 'add support' for the Custom Logo in the functions.php:

**--functions.php--**

```
 add_theme_support( 'custom-logo' );
```

---

Then I added these variables in the *index.php* file so that the twig templates would be able use the url:

**--index.php--**

```
$custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
$custom_logo_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $custom_logo_id , 'full' );
$custom_logo_url_esc_url = 

$context['custom_logo_id'] = $custom_logo_id;
$context['custom_logo_url'] = $custom_logo_url;
```

---

Inside the *base.twig* file I'm including a *menu.twig* file like this:

**--base.twig--**

```
 {% include "menu.twig" with {'menu': menu.get_items} %}
```

---

And in the *menu.twig* I have this (sizes there are just for testing):

**--menu.twig--**

```
        <a href="{{ site.url|e('esc_url') }}">
        <picture>
            <source srcset="{{ custom_logo_url|towebp }}" type="image/webp">
            <source srcset="{{ custom_logo_url|tojpg }}" type="image/jpeg">                 

            <img src="{{ custom_logo_url|resize(400, 300) }}" srcset="{{ custom_logo_url|resize(200, 150)|retina(1) }} 1x,
                {{ custom_logo_url|resize(800, 600)|retina(2) }}  2x,
                {{ custom_logo_url|resize(1600, 1200)|retina(3) }}  3x,
                {{ custom_logo_url|resize(2400, 2400)|retina(4) }}  4x">
        </picture>                                  
        </a>
```

The logo is outputting OK on the homepage, but nowhere else. Any idea how to tweak this or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

To answer to my question...

Add theme support for 'custom-logo'. This snippet goes under the last 'add_theme_support' line:

**--functions.php--**

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-logo' );
```

---

In functions.php, you need to add more '$context' for twig. to reference.

For example - $context['foo'] = bar will be used as {{ foo }} in the twig template, and output 'bar' to html when rendered by php.

To add the logo $context, the functions.php file goes **FROM** this:

**--functions.php (before)--**

```
 public function add_to_context( $context ) {
    $context['foo'] = 'bar';
    $context['stuff'] = 'I am a value set in your functions.php file';
    $context['notes'] = 'These values are available everytime you call Timber::get_context();';
    $context['menu'] = new Timber\Menu();
    $context['site'] = $this;
    return $context;
}
```

---

**TO** this (the two indented lines are needed):

**--functions.php (after)--**

```
 public function add_to_context( $context ) {
    $context['foo'] = 'bar';
    $context['stuff'] = 'I am a value set in your functions.php file';
    $context['notes'] = 'These values are available everytime you call Timber::get_context();';
    $context['menu'] = new Timber\Menu();
    $context['site'] = $this;
     $custom_logo_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' ), 'full' );
     $context['custom_logo_url'] = $custom_logo_url;    
    return $context;
}
```

---

*Base.twig* still includes the *menu.twig*

**--base.twig--**

```
 {% include "menu.twig" with {'menu': menu.get_items} %}
```

---

And the *menu.twig* markup again. Adjust the 'resize' ranges as needed.

**--menu.twig--**

```
        <a class="logo-link-to-home" href="{{ site.url|e('esc_url') }}">
        <picture>
            <source srcset="{{ custom_logo_url|towebp }}" type="image/webp">
            <source srcset="{{ custom_logo_url|tojpg }}" type="image/jpeg">                 
            {# <img src="{{custom_logo_url|tojpg}}" alt=""> #}
            <img alt="sioux city electric logo" src="{{ custom_logo_url|resize(400, 300) }}" srcset="{{ custom_logo_url|resize(200, 150)|retina(1) }} 1x,
                {{ custom_logo_url|resize(800, 600)|retina(2) }}  2x,
                {{ custom_logo_url|resize(1600, 1200)|retina(3) }}  3x,
                {{ custom_logo_url|resize(2400, 2400)|retina(4) }}  4x">
        </picture>                                  
        </a>
```